# For two different widgets, how do I get the boolean value in one from the second widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, widget, boolean, parameter-passing

I am using two different widgets and need some data from one widget to another. This data(boolean isGoalAchieved) is calculated in goal_card_detail.dart widget and I need to use it to rename button in goal_card_data.dart page. How can I achieve this?

**goal_card_details.dart**

```
class GoalCardDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final double goalAmount;
  final double currentBalance;
  final double monthlyAmount;
  final bool isWaitingForApproval;

  const GoalCardDetails({
    Key? key,
    required this.goalAmount,
    required this.currentBalance,
    required this.monthlyAmount,
    required this.isWaitingForApproval,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    final double remainingAmount = goalAmount - currentBalance;
    final int remainingPeriod = (remainingAmount / monthlyAmount).ceil();
    late String remainingTitle;

    final bool isGoalAchieved = remainingPeriod <= 0;

    if (isGoalAchieved) {
      remainingTitle = l10n.goalAchieved;
    } else {
      remainingTitle = AppUtils.periodToDoubleYears(context,
          periodInMonths: remainingPeriod);
    }
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        if (!isWaitingForApproval)
          _getListTile(
            title: _getTitle(remainingTitle),
            subtitle: !isGoalAchieved ? l10n.remainingSubtitle : null,
          ),
        _getListTile(
          title: _getTitle('$monthlyAmountText€'),
          subtitle: l10n.monthlyAmountSubtitle,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

goal_card_data.dart

```
class GoalCardData extends StatelessWidget {
  final Objective goal;

  const GoalCardData({
    Key? key,
    required this.goal,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AppLocalizations l10n = context.l10n;


    final bool isWaitingForApproval =
        goal.status == ObjectiveStatuses.WITHDRAW_PENDING_APPROVAL &&
            goal.status != ObjectiveStatuses.CREATED;


    return  
              ButtonBar(
                alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                children: [
                  AppButtons.button(
                      onPressed: () => AppUtils.snackBarNotImplemented(context),
                      outline: true,
                      appButtonSize: AppButtonsSize.small,
                      child: Text(l10n.buttonDetails)),
                  if (isStarted)
                    AppButtons.button(
                      onPressed: () => appShowAlertDialog(
                        context,
                        dialogType: AppAlerdDialogType.startSavingDialog,
                      ),
                      appButtonSize: AppButtonsSize.small,
                      child: Text(context.l10n.buttonStartGoal),
                    )
                  else if (!isWaitingForApproval && currentBalance > 0)
                    AppButtons.button(
                        onPressed: () {
                         ....;
                        },
                        child: Text(l10n.buttonWithdraw))
                  // else if (????)
                  //   AppButtons.button(
                  //       onPressed: () {
                  //         Navigator.of(context)
                  //             .pushNamed(ExtractionBody.routeName);
                  //       },
                  //       child: Text(l10n.buttonExtractionRequest))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

As I said, my goal is to add AppButtons based on the boolean "isGoalAchieved" in goal_card_details.

like this;

```
   else if (isGoalAchieved)
                     AppButtons.button(
                         onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context)
                             .pushNamed(ExtractionBody.routeName);
                       },
                       child: Text(l10n.buttonExtractionRequest))
```

Comment: create a file `globals.dart` -> declare `isGoalAchieved` here with an initial value -> now use this variable in both the widgets.

Comment: just create function in `goal_card_data.dart`  , why you make it more complicated by calculating the data in another class

Comment: Hoş geldin Nazlı, passing down parameters down the widget tree through constructors might do the trick in this case like @Sheetal Ghori suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the boolean or any value using the constructor.

or you can also pass arguments if you need value in navigation

[You can check this for how to pass string/bool/Any value and access it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73201777/12054032)

Answer (score 0):

both your class is `StatelessWidget` , then just create this function inside `goal_card_data.dart` . no need to calculate in another class

```
// i just copied your calculation from  goal_card_details.dart

 final double remainingAmount = goalAmount - currentBalance;
 final int remainingPeriod = (remainingAmount / monthlyAmount).ceil();

 bool isgoalachived = isGoalAchieved = remainingPeriod <= 0;

 return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      children: [
        if (isWaitingForApproval) const GoalCardPendingLabel(),

        .........................

        else if (isgoalachived ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Provider package to manage your state. Wrap your `GoalCardData` with a Provider class then store your data in this Provider. Then you listen to the date change in `GoalCardData`, after the data change, you notify the widgets listen to that Provider